# What's causing iTunes to randomly display a 4002 error?

Tags: itunes, error, itunes-store, dialog

Once every day or two, iTunes seemingly randomly displays a 4002 error:

[image: error screenshot]

This is particularly puzzling to me, as the majority of the time (if not always) iTunes is in the background, and has been for a while. What exactly does the error signify, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the exact version of iTunes you are using?

Comment: 10.6.1, but I haven't seen it in a while.

Answer (score 3):

I got rid of this pesky error by

1. turning iTunes Match off
2. quit iTunes
3. launch iTunes
4. turn iTunes Match on

The first time iTunes complained with error 5002 during Match startup, but then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Google seems to think it's an iTunes Genius error.  Try turning off Genius from `Store -> Turn off Genius`.

If that doesn't resolve your issue, if Genius is not on, or if it's too important to turn off, post more info about your system and we'll try to help.

Comment: I've turned off Genius but the problem persists.

Comment: I'm running the latest iTunes (10.6.1) on a late 2009 MBP. I'm on OS 10.7.3 and I'm logged in to the iTunes Store with my Apple ID. There's no Genius restrictions in iTunes preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I have been importing quite a few songs into iTunes v 10.7 (21) on OS X 10.8.2 and this error is popping up when the upload process has a hiccup. Even if you are not currently in a state when you would expect uploading to the iTunes Match cloud, the software can run a sync and throw this error.

There's nothing you can normally do on your end other than disconnect from the internet and wait for the servers to clear up. In my case, no action was needed to resume uploads. The iTunes process was patient and resumed once a short timeout passed.